# What constitutes marketing?

Tags: discussion, scope

On **Android Enthusiasts** it states:

> The following topics are expressly off-topic here:
>
> ```
> Marketing your Android app or doing market research
> ```

If in the process of writing an App, assuming no need for help with writing/developing the code, would asking other enthusiasts on **Android Enthusiasts** for feedback regarding the App, and thus trying the App (providing a link to it), be considered as marketing?

Would the likely end market impact upon whether or not this would constitute marketing? In other words, if the intention were to provide the app freely. If so at what level does Marketing come into play? If the app includes advertising or in-app purchases.

Comment: Soliciting feedback or asking for help with testing your app is not a specific question, so though it isn't really "marketing" it's still outside the purpose of this site. There was at one time an attempt to create a program to pair willing beta testers with developers, but it didn't seem to get enough traction to really take off, as I recall.

Comment: If you're looking for feedback/testers, your best bet would probably be a forum like reddit or maybe our chatroom here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This site is for Android users.  As a rule of thumb, do not ask any question where the *question* does not come from the perspective of an end user doing end user things.

Marketing and charging money are obviously related, but are distinct concepts; you can do one without the other.  So whether your app is free is not relevant, and asking for feedback absolutely counts as "market research".

As Eldarerathis notes, we also do not accept open-ended polling or anything of that kind.  Questions should be specific and should require answers that can be determined to be correct or not — not just an opinion, like feedback.